# How do I check if a many-to-many relationship exists in a Django template?

Tags: django, django-models

In this code example, "teaches_for" is the name of a many-to-many field that relates a Performer model to a School model. I want to include this particular block only if at least one relationship between a Performer and a Teacher model exists.

Here's my non-working code:

```
{% if performer.teaches_for.exists %}
<h3>{{performer.first_name}} teaches at these schools...</h3>

<ul>
    {% for school in performer.teaches_for.all %}
    <li><a href="/schools/{{school.id}}">{{ school.name }}</a></li>
    {%  endfor %}
</ul>

{% endif %}
```

The line that's wrong is `{% if performer.teaches_for.exists %}`. What can I replace it with which will be True if at least one relationship exists, but False otherwise?

The relevant field in my Performer model looks like this:

```
    teaches_for = models.ManyToManyField(
        School,
        verbose_name="Teaches at this school",
        blank=True,
        related_name="teachers",
    )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In django 3.2.4 Hagyn's answer needs correction: `{% if performer.teaches_for.all.exists() %}`
And now it works as needed

Comment: Thank you Damir! I edit my answer with your correction.

Comment: You don't have to use brace `()` inside **template**. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/57166195/6143954

Comment: @NKSM yeah, but it didn't cause a correct work without brackets for me, so...

Answer (score 6):

Try `{% if performer.teaches_for.all.exists %}`.

Comment: You don't have to use brace `()` inside **template**. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls

Answer (score 1):

The `{% for school in performer.teaches_for.all %}` loop will execute zero times if there are no schools. So put the header into the loop with a test on `forloop.first`.

```
{% for school in performer.teaches_for.all %}
    {% if forloop.first %}
       <h3>{{performer.first_name}} teaches at these schools...</h3><ul>
    {% endif %}

    <li><a href="/schools/{{school.id}}">{{ school.name }}</a></li>

   {% if forloop.last}</ul> {%endif%}
{%  endfor %}
```

If I've cut-and-pasted from the question right.